# APPIUM, how to get x and y coordinates for swiping

Tags: android, appium, python-appium

In the Appium [documentation](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/writing-running-appium/appium-bindings/#scroll-to), it says that i have to pass in an x and y value. How can I know the x and y value of a section i want to to swipe left or right on. I am using uiautomationviewer (Android), do I need any tools?

```
driver.swipe(start_x=75, start_y=500, end_x=75, end_y=0, duration=800)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any tools for getting the x, y values.

Just enable this option in your Android device / Emulator:

```
Settings > Developer options > Enable 'Pointer location'
```

After enabling this once you tap on screen -> x, y locator values will be displayed in top bar.

Enable Pointer Location:
[image: Pointer location]

x, y values:
[image: x, y values]