# Unable to click a button (testing)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium-android, appium-desktop

My project is automation testing on voot app using appium(android),selenium (java)
I am using appium desktop inspector to locate the id/xpath of an element and copying that in eclipse.
There is a "GOT IT" button on the home page without an id or xpath, how do i go about it

```
package tests;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption;
public class test extends BaseClass{
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
            MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.tv.v18.viola:id/btn_login_mobile");
            el1.click();
            System.out.println("Completed test1");
            MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.tv.v18.viola:id/hint_text");
            
            System.out.println("Completed test2");
            driver.hideKeyboard();
            MobileElement el3=(MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.tv.v18.viola:id/btn_login");
            el3.click();
            MobileElement el4=(MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.tv.v18.viola:id/password");
            
            System.out.println("completed test2");
            driver.hideKeyboard();
            }
    @Test
        public void test2() {
            MobileElement el5=(MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.tv.v18.viola:id/btn_login");
            el5.click();
            System.out.println("Completed test3");
        }
    @Test
    public void test3() {
        MobileElement el6=(MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.tv.v18.viola:id/btn_home_page");
        el6.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        TouchAction action0=new TouchAction(driver); //not working
        action0.tap(PointOption.point(612,1329)).perform();//not working
    }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlNWU.jpg)

Comment: Post a code instead of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

driver.findElementByName("GOT IT").click();

or

use the position of the button and make it.([APPIUM, how to get x and y coordinates for swiping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036650/appium-how-to-get-x-and-y-coordinates-for-swiping))